# php's preg_match_all: split string by first character

Tags: php, regex, string

I'd like to use PHP's `preg_match_all` function to split a string by a certain caracter, while the 'certain character' is the first character in the string, e.g.:

```
$pattern = '/#(?P<word>[.....])';
$string = 'one#two#three';
$matches = array();
preg_match_all($pattern,$string, $matches);
// expected $matches array: $matches['word'] = 'one','two','three'
```

So the "split field character" is itself part of the pattern (the first char).

Is this even possible? if yes, how?

Comment: I dont get it, but you can try `$pattern = '/(\w+)/'` instead, or even explode() function

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)?

```
$matches = explode('#', $string);
```